# Mat Select value is too long for the input

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a mat select and when the user selects a value it doesn't look good in the selection box

I have the text wrapping when the user opens the selection, however when they choose the selection it is cut off with no space between the last ellipses and the dropdown arrow and the ellipses cuts off the word.

Is there a way to make this look more professional Like dynamically add the ellipses after a whole word  for example

Instead of
**Pizza but this is a lo...**

It would be 
**Pizza but this is a ...**
or

**Hi my name ...**

instead of

**Hi my name is sta...**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

 foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza but this is along value that looks bad'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

/** No CSS for this example */
::ng-deep .mat-select-content{
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
margin: 1rem 0;
overflow: visible;
line-height: initial;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
white-space: normal;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhxdfy-2hi8zw?file=app/select-overview-example.ts

**EDIT:**
Here is the photo of what I am talking about. I want the ellipses to show after the last whole word.

So it should say  Pizza but this is a ...

The image cuts the word "long" in half and it doesn't look good. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css of your stackblitz that do the job for me. it add 5px of padding between the arrow and the ellipsis.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-content{
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
/* ::ng-deep .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
margin: 1rem 0;
overflow: visible;
line-height: initial;
word-wrap: break-word;
} */

::ng-deep .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-value{
  /* adapt to add space between ellipsis and text */
  padding-right: 5px; 
}
```

As you can see I have removed some of your css that I didn't need, do as you wish with that !
For the word splitting case, there is no way for you to do it easily. An idea could be to build a pipe that cut your text after the last space if it's too long and add the ellipsis (unless the pipe get the value after the css is applied, I don't know).
Honestly, I don't think it's worth spending your time on it, the result is clean. maybe displaying the whole value (In a tooltip of  tag) can be even better.

Comment: This looks good for the dropdown but I am talking about after the selection has been made. See the update to the original question

Comment: As i said there is no easy solution for that. I don't understand why you say it does not looks good, it should even you to think of a way to display the whole data. Professionaly speaking, it is required.